# Domino path algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I've got some (I hope) easy question about algorithm that can resolve the "domino path" problem. I'm looking for resolution that will resolved this problem in less then O(n^2) complexity.

I've got a group of n-points (n in [1,100 000], every point is diffrent) with x and y coords:
`(0,1)
(1,3)
(1,2)
(2,4)
(3,5)
(4,2)
(5,0)`

I'm looking for the "path" from start point (0,y) to the end point (x,0) (the other point need to be sticked like domino block). In this example the path will be looking like this: `(0,1) > (1,3) > (3,5) > (5,0)`. If the points will create more than one path - choose any of them. Could it be done is less than O(n^2)?

**EDIT**: Thanks for graph algorithm, but can it be done without it? I'm looking for some tricky recurrence algorith or something like this.

Comment: Any additional information? Is a path guaranteed to exist? Are certain ranges or combinations of domino blocks guaranteed to be in the input? A graph algorithm will handle all of these cases nicely. Using a less general-purpose algorithm usually assumes something about the input.

Comment: _Is a path guaranteed to exist_ No. Input may contain also just a single point like this (0,3) - in that case output should be: NO PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You should read up on [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) which runs in O(E+V log V) where `E` is the number of edges in your graph and `V` is the number of vertices. A [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) would also work, since the graph is unweighted. That would run in O(E+V) time.

Though these are common ways of solving this problem, they are [by no means the only ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Comment: Dijkstra's not the only one that solves shortest path: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem (Bellman Ford, A*, Warshall)

Comment: Thanks, @hakononakani, that is a good point to make. I have incorporated your link into my answer.

Comment: But can it be done without using the graph algorithm?

Comment: @kowal66b, this problem represents naturally as a graph problem and there is an extremely wide and complete theory to solving such problems using graphs. Unless you have specific reasons to avoiding a graph representation, it is probably best to embrace it. Are you suggesting there may be a "trick" that allows you to efficiently solve your problem without using a full graph algorithm?

Comment: Someone suggested me that problem can be solved by using the Eight queens puzzle algorithm (or part of it).

Comment: This is overkill for this problem, since the graph is unweighted.

Comment: @kowal66b, I am not personally sure how to use an Eight Queens approach here (there are many algorithms for solving that problem). A breadth-first search is likely to be the most simplistic thing you can do, and has a time complexity that is linear in the size of your input.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the problem in `O(n)` using a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29), similar to a [Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). You do not need Dijkstra's algorithm, but you do need to store your input as a graph.

Pseudocode:

```
Q = a FIFO queue
Enque all pairs (0, y)
while Q not empty:
  remove an element p from Q
  Enque all unvisited nodes reachable from p
  if you enqued a (x, 0) node, you have a solution
```

You can get the path back by keeping track of your distances for example. If `d[i] = cost to reach node i`, then find a node `k` connected to your solution node for which `d[k] + 1 = d[solution]`, then repeat the process for `k`.

Comment: Which graph representation should I use for that? Numbers of nodes can be even 100 000.

Comment: @kowal66b - adjacency list representation would work best in this case.

Comment: if I'm having right now a tab with all information about distance how should I path back to get respond?

Right now I'm having a struct like this: 

`struct blocks
{
 int nose;
int tail;
int distance;
};
`
It's nicely filled in, so what should I do next?

EDIT: How to add /n to this code comment?!